# CakePHP: get current model name in a controller

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm creating a behaviour that needs to log the current model name. How can I get the current model name from within a controller in CakePHP?

Comment: What do you mean by “current” model name? Why are you mentioning the controller if it’s a model behavior you’re creating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your architecture is flawed when you want to get a controllers primary model name from a behavior. That's a violation of the MVC pattern. Your app should have fat models and skinny controllers.

Your Behavior already has the model instance as it is required to be passed to behaviors. You can get the name from the model object:

```
// Cake 2.x
$Model->name
// Cake 3.x
$Table->name()
```

or it's alias

```
// Cake 2.x
$Model->alias
// Cake 3.x
$Table->alias()
```

Comment: However, the title question makes sense when trying to extend a controller, and google results are likely to land here. To get the current model name within a controller, use `$this->modelClass`. It's a property of class Controller in CakePHP 2.x, and a property of Cake\Datasource\ModelAwareTrait in CakePHP 3.x.

Comment: $Table->alias() and $Table->name() stop working at some point before CakePHP 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier example don't work, but it's work for me:

```
// Cake 3.x    
$object->repository()->alias()
```

Answer (score 0):

since Cakephp 3 you can just use

```
$this->modelClass
```

Answer (score 0):

For cake 3.4 + and 4.x (CakePHP is on 4.2 at the time of writing this) you can use the following:

```
// For table
$Table->getTable();

// For alias    
$Table->getAlias();
```